# Angular lazy loading routing

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have lazy load app routing like below:

**app.routing.ts**

```
{
  path: 'reports',
  loadChildren: () => import('../Reporting/reporting.module').then(m => m.ReportingModule)
},
{
  path: 'report-builder',
  loadChildren: () => import('../Reporting/reporting.module').then(m => m.ReportingModule)
},
```

My lazy load module routes look like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: '', component: ReportsComponent },
        { path: ':id',component: ViewReport},
        { path: '**', component: ViewReport }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: '', component: ReportBuilderComponent },
        { path: 'edit/:id', component: DesignReport },
        { path: '**', component: DesignReport }
      ]
    }
```

I am trying to achieve, when user clicks on reports route, navigate to default Reportscomponent and when clicked on reportBuilder route, navigate to ReportBuilderComponent.

How to achieve this.

Comment: Simplest way to do this is create another routing module for report-builder path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

Create two modules one for reports and one for report-builder.

*app.report-routing.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
       path: '',
       children: [
           { path: '', component: ReportsComponent },
           { path: ':id',component: ViewReport},
           { path: '**', component: ViewReport }]
    }
]
```

Configure above routes in report.module

*app.report-builder-routing.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: '', component: ReportBuilderComponent },
        { path: 'edit/:id', component: DesignReport },
        { path: '**', component: DesignReport }
      ]
    }
]
```

configure above routes in report-builder.module

*app.routing.js*

```
{
  path: 'reports',
  loadChildren: () => import('../Reporting/report.module').then(m => m.ReportingModule)
},
{
  path: 'report-builder',
  loadChildren: () => import('../Reporting/report-builder.module').then(m => m.ReportBuilderModule)
}
```

**Method 2**

*app.report-routing.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        { path: '', component: ReportsComponent },
        { path: ':id',component: ViewReport},
        { path: '**', component: ViewReport }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: 'builder',
      children: [
        { path: '', component: ReportBuilderComponent },
        { path: 'edit/:id', component: DesignReport },
        { path: '**', component: DesignReport }
      ]
    }
```

*app.routing.ts*

```
{
  path: 'report',
  loadChildren: () => import('../Reporting/reporting.module').then(m => m.ReportingModule)
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Reference
[Angular: Lazy loading feature modules](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bampqpxajma?embed=1&file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

Comment: But i would like to do in same module as they both share same services and common components

Comment: In that case try method 2

Comment: With method 1 you can have */report* and */report-builder* url endpoints and with method 2 you can have */report* and */report/builder* endpoints